# How do I make an option (not argument of the option) mandatory in zparseopts?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zsh, options

In the example bellow:

```
function zp () {
    zparseopts -E -walk:=o_walk
    echo "walk: $o_walk"
}
```

I get the following output:

```
$ zp --walk "Walking"
walk            : --walk Walking
$ zp --walk
zp:zparseopts:2: missing argument for option: -walk
walk            :
```

Here the argument of the option is mandatory so I am getting this error.

How can I make the option mandatory so that I must pass `--walk` to `zp` else it will throw an error?

Comment: Some might argue it's not an option at all, if it's not optional :P An alternative would be to take the mandatory argument from the regular argument list without using a preceding option flag at all. Though of course the are examples of existing tools that have mandatory option arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly about `zparseopts`, but I think `getopt` doesn't have that and I only see references to mandatory arguments [in the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zparseopts) for `zparseopts`.

You can always just check manually if the resulting option is set:

```
function zp () {
    if ! zparseopts -E -walk:=o_walk; then
        return 1
    fi
    if [ $#o_walk = 0 ]; then
        echo "required option --walk missing" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    echo "walk: $o_walk"
}
```

Here, `zparseopts` fails if the option is given without an argument, and the second `if` explicitly tests if the `o_walk` array has any items.

Using an associative array to collect the arguments is also an option, and to me it feels cleaner:

```
function zp () {
    if ! zparseopts -E -A opts -walk: ; then
        return 1
    fi
    if ! [ ${opts[--walk]+x} ]; then
        echo "required option --walk missing" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    echo "walk: $opts[--walk]"
}
```